# Why can I not find the file if I give the relative path but I can find it with the direct path?

Tags: php, mime

I'm trying to use mime->addAttachment() to add an attachmen to an email i'm about to send

relative path: `../../clientdata/client1/attachments/file.txt`

direct path: `/home/hosting/site.eu/html/ssl/clientdata/client1/attachments/file.txt`

script location: `/home/hosting/site.eu/html/ssl/work/php_scripts/send_email.php`

send_email.php is executed using:

```
exec("php /home/hosting/site.eu/html/ssl/work/php_scripts/send_email.php");
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

The code i'm using to add the attachment:

```
$f = 'ssl.site.eu/clientdata/client1/attachments/file1.txt';  
$arr_file = explode('/', $f, 2);
$file_path = '/home/hosting/site.eu/html/ssl/'.$arr_file[1]; //this works
// $file_path = '../../'.$arr_file[1]; // this doesn't work;
$mime->addAttachment($file_path,'application/octet-stream');
```

Comment: You need to give us a bit more details on how you are trying to "find" the file with PHP. Show us the code where you are trying to "find" the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware the working directory of your process.

Now does the following code give the currect path?
`echo getcwd().$relative_path;`

[PHP getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Comment: hm, it gives the path to the file that ran the exec(). That's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

if you include some PHP files that relative the file that codes execute,you must be sure that you include these files relative the process's current directory,but not the file contains current executing codes.